# How can I make a jQuery script aware of a Codeigniter variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have been developing a blogging application with CodeIgniter 3.1.8 and Twig. I am currently working on making a **newsletter subscription** system.

I have created a table named *newsletter* with 3 columns: `id`, `email` and `subscription_date`.

The newsletter subscription form:

```
<div id="messags" class="is-hidden h-text-center">
  <div class="success is-hidden alert-box alert-box--success">You have successfully subscribed to our newsletter</div>
  <div class="fail is-hidden alert-box alert-box--error">Sorry, the newsletter subscription filed</div>
</div>
<form name="newsletter" method="post" action="{{base_url}}newsletter/subscribe" id="newsletterForm" class="group" novalidate>
  <input type="email" value="{{set_value('email') | striptags}}" name="email" class="email" data-rule-required="true" placeholder="Your Email Address"> 
  <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="subscribe">
</form>
```

The **Newsletter_model** model:

```
class Newsletter_model extends CI_Model {
    public function subscriber_exists() {   
        $query = $this->db->get_where('newsletter', ['email' => $this->input->post('email')]);
        return $query->num_rows() > 0;
    }

    public function add_subscriber() {
        $data = [
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'subscription_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        ];
        return $this->db->insert('newsletter', $data);
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I use the `subscriber_exists()` to make sure there are *no duplicate emails*.

The **Newsletter** controller is quite simple:

```
class Newsletter extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

  public function subscribe(){
    $data['is_new_subscriber'] = true;
    if (!$this->Newsletter_model->subscriber_exists()) {
      $this->Newsletter_model->add_subscriber();
    } else {
      $data['is_new_subscriber'] = false;
    }
  } 
}
```

#### The problem

I use jQuery AJAX to submit the form and the script is unaware of the `is_new_subscriber` variable:

```
(function($) {

    // Add subscriber via AJAX
    $("#newsletterForm").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                email: true
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var form = $("#newsletterForm"),
                $fields = form.find('input[type="email"]'),
                url = form.attr('action'),
                data = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: function() {
                    $('#messags').slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
                    if (is_new_subscriber == true) {
                        $fields.val('');
                        $('#messags .success').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#messags .fail').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

### UPDATE

Adding echo `json_encode($data)` to the `subscribe()` and changing the `submitHandler` to the below ddi not splve the issue:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  var form = $("#newsletterForm"),
  $fields = form.find('input[type="email"]'),
  url = form.attr('action'),
  data = form.serialize();
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function() {
      $('#messags').slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
      $fields.val('');
      if (data.is_new_subscriber == true) {
        $('#messags .success').show();
      } else {
        $('#messags .fail').show();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Why not echo the variable within the script, or echo it to a data attribute anywhere on your site?

Comment: @NicoHaase I am not sure I understand your suggestion.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't do anything with the `$data` variable, after you populate it. You could for example return it JSON-encoded.

```
  public function subscribe(){
    $data['is_new_subscriber'] = true;
    if (!$this->Newsletter_model->subscriber_exists()) {
      $this->Newsletter_model->add_subscriber();
    } else {
      $data['is_new_subscriber'] = false;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Then, in the success callback of your JS code you need to reference it:

```
...
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#messags').slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
                    if (data.is_new_subscriber == true) {
                        $fields.val('');
                        $('#messags .success').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#messags .fail').show();
                    }
                }
...
```

Comment: @RazvanZamfir this should work, if you use dataType='json' in your ajax settings, otherwise you need to JSON.parse(data) in your success. Anyway you can always console.dir(data) in your success to see what you get back

Comment: @Vickel If I use `JSON.parse(data)'` I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0`

Comment: @RazvanZamfir in your success? using Zoli's code?

Comment: @Vickel Yes. In the `success` method.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you must have something echo'd out somewhere in your php, e.g. an error message or a print_r()...which then is sent via ajax together with $data) and throws the JSON.parse error, as it is not a valid json string anymore. Try it with a simple array (to debug), you'll see it works...

Comment: jQuery will make an "intelligent guess" on the response type (as per https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). This may however only work when the content type header is correctly set. In any case, like @Vickel wrote, explicitly specifying `dataType` (set to 'json') should do the trick.. If it's not, then there is additional output which is breaking the correct json formatted output. Please open devtools in your browser (usually F12), go to the network tab and inspect the response of the ajax call.

Comment: I did specify the `dataType` as JSON, and the form stopped working altogether. The form _does_ work correctly (it did so from the beginning). The messages do not.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir You must help us with some debugging info, otherwise we cannot help you :) See my previous commit of what would be needed.

Comment: Also please update the original question with the new version of your code. Both PHP and JS.

Comment: There is no nwe version

Comment: Since you're not willing to give us debug info from the browser devtools, let's try another thing. Please change `echo json_encode($data);` to `die(json_encode($data));`. This should help avoiding eventual additional output. Let's see if it gets you closer to the solution.

Comment: @Vickel Here is **[what worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66639501/4512005)** for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

In the controller, I added `echo json_encode($data)`:

```
class Newsletter extends CI_Controller {
  
  public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

  public function subscribe(){
    $data['is_new_subscriber'] = true;
    if (!$this->Newsletter_model->subscriber_exists()) {
      $this->Newsletter_model->add_subscriber();
    } else {
      $data['is_new_subscriber'] = false;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

The script:

```
(function($) {

  // Add subscriber via AJAX
  $("#newsletterForm").validate({
    rules: {
      email: {
        email: true
      }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var form = $("#newsletterForm"),
      $fields = form.find('input[type="email"]'),
      url = form.attr('action'),
      data = form.serialize();
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
          $('#messags').slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
          $fields.val('');
          if (response.is_new_subscriber === true) {
            $('#messags .success').show();
             $('#messags .notnew').hide();
          } else {
            $('#messags .notnew').show();
          }
        },
        error: function() {
          $('#messags .fail').show();
        }
      });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="messags" class="is-hidden h-text-center">
    <div class="success is-hidden alert-box alert-box--success">You have successfully subscribed to our newsletter</div>
    <div class="notnew is-hidden alert-box alert-box--info">You are already subscribed</div>
    <div class="fail is-hidden alert-box alert-box--error">Sorry, the newsletter subscription filed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *In the controller, I added echo json_encode($data):* this is what @Zoli wrote in his answer!